# IBM Mobilefirst 7.0 - JSONStore Error during provision cannot locate symbol "CBB_add_u16"

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, mobilefirst-studio, android-7.0-nougat

I'm deploying an app built with IBM Mobilefirst Platform Studio v 7.0.0.00.20160526-2153 on an Android 7 - Nexus 5 (aosp_hammerhead-userdbug 7.0 NRD90M) and it's tracing the next error related to JSONStore:

```
09-12 14:19:39.761 17860-17902/com.myapp.MobileApp E/JSONSTORE: JSONStoreLogger.logError in JSONStoreLogger.java:189 :: Error during provision
                                                                   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "CBB_add_u16" referenced by "/system/lib/libssl.so"...
                                                                       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)
                                                                       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
                                                                       at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:143)
                                                                       at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:136)
                                                                       at com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.openDatabaseIfNecessary(DatabaseManager.java:179)
                                                                       at com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseManager.checkDatabaseAgainstSchema(DatabaseManager.java:98)
                                                                       at com.worklight.jsonstore.database.DatabaseSchema.isSchemaMismatched(DatabaseSchema.java:417)
                                                                       at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.provisionDatabase(WLJSONStore.java:149)
                                                                       at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.openCollections(WLJSONStore.java:345)
                                                                       at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.initializeCollection(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:147)
                                                                       at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.databaseActionDispatch(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:133)
                                                                       at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.actionDispatch(BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.java:36)
                                                                       at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseActionDispatcher.dispatch(BaseActionDispatcher.java:90)
                                                                       at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:79)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
09-12 14:19:39.765 17860-17902/com.myapp.MobileApp E/MyApp: /***** 
09-12 14:19:39.769 17860-17902/com.myapp.MobileApp E/MyApp: PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE
09-12 14:19:39.773 17860-17902/com.myapp.MobileApp E/MyApp:  *****/
09-12 14:19:39.777 17860-17902/com.myapp.MobileApp E/wl.jsonstore: {"src":"initCollection","err":-1,"msg":"PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE","col":"App","usr":"app","doc":{},"res":{}}
```

Although the app is capable of consume adapter services from the Mobilefirst server (the server is tracing when the app calls an adapter).

The app works fine on lower Android SOs (4.4, 5.X, 6.X).

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with the JSONStore support for Android 7.

Keep an eye open on the following blog post, which will be updated once an iFix is available: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/05/mobilefirst-platform-compatibility-for-android-n/